# I work in a hospital or I work in the hospital

Tags: definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I am wondering :
I work in a hospital or I work in the hospital ?
She works on a plane or she works on the plane ?
thanks

Comment: Both are good. It depends on the context -- any [a] hospital or a particular [the] hospital whose identity has already been established.

Answer (score 1):

If you use "the hospital" you are referring to a specific hospital(Ex. St. John's) and are therefore focusing on the exact place she works in.

If she works in "a hospital", it just means she is a doctor, nurse, etc.. and the place where she works is not important. In this case the focus of the conversation lies on her job.